# Rails 3.1 - Need to show a JS pop-up with the contents of a field - can it be easily done?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, ruby-on-rails-3.1, popup

I have limited screen space for a table that I'm displaying, so I'm showing a truncated view of a description field:

```
<td><%= simple_format car.description.truncate(200, :separator => ' ') %></td>
```

I need a mouse over or click event to generate a simple pop up window (an "alert", a "tool tip", a "dialog", etc.) displaying the full contents of the car.description field.

I'm an admitted JS rookie.  All the JS-Rails tutorials/information that I'm seeing are focused on unobtrusive JS, dealing mostly with AJAX/remote server interactions.  I'm not seeing anything that helps understand how you can use data from your Rails application in rich JS UI features within your views.  I saw a tool tip gem, but with that gem, tool tip content is statically generated, and tool tips are held in their own table.  It provides no way to generate a tool tip on the fly, based on a field pulled from the database.

Is there some very, very simple way to have JS pop-up the text held in a Rails field?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'generate a tool tip on the fly'? (1) when user hovers on the truncated text, an ajax call is made to retrieve full information and a hidden modal is populated with the data and then revealed? (2) the full information is put in a hidden modal during the view generation and on mouse hover reveals the modal?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of (2).  My view already has the full contents of car.description.  I just need a simple way to have it pop up on a mouse over or click.  I don't understand the process to generate the hidden modal that you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a dummy rails project @ https://github.com/rahul/SO_9347471. I used the modal library provided by twitter's bootstrap @ http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html.

Download that project and,

1. bundle install
2. rake db:migrate
3. rake db:seed
4. rails server
5. hit localhost:3000 in your browser

I created a modal div for each car and when the bootstrap javascript library loads, it converts all such divs into bootstrap modals (and hides them, waiting for a user to click on the truncated text)

====================================

Take a look a

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

and then

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

They contain an easy to follow documentation to help you get started. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Rahul, thanks for the response.  I've seen a lot of these JS code examples - they don't help me.  I need a Rails code example.  I don't understand the basics of Rails using JQueryUI. I'm guessing that I have to put some of the jqueryui dialog() example code somewhere in my project (in the .js.erb file? or in the .html.erb file in <script> tags?), and then I have to somehow tie it to DOM/HTML items in my view. Finally I have to set it up so that when a DOM/HTML item is clicked the dialog() is launched with car.description in the dialog() window.  Have you seen a "Rails using jqueryui" example?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this together.  I've downloaded it and can see that there is a level of Ruby and JS integrated together.  I'm not familiar with SLIM, so I'll have to learn it and try to translate back to html.erb.  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would post my final solution.  I was able to solve this using strictly HTML and CSS - no JS required.  Whenever the cursor roles over the truncated description, a pop-up window will immediately apear and then disappear as the mouse it moved away.

Here is the HTML I used:

```
<a href="#" class="tt"><%=  @car.description.truncate(90, :separator => ' ') %>
    <span class="overlay"><%=  simple_format @car.description %></span>
</a>
```

Then I added the following CSS:

```
/*  *****************  tool tips  ********************/
a.tt p {
    position:relative;
    z-index:24;
    color: #0066CC;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a.tt span{ display: none; }
/*background:; ie hack, something must be changed in a for ie to execute it*/
a.tt:hover{ z-index:25; color: #aaaaff; background:;}
a.tt:hover span.tooltip{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:25;
    top:0px; left:0;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    color: #993300;
    text-align: center;
    filter: alpha(opacity:90);
    KHTMLOpacity: 0.90;
    MozOpacity: 0.90;
    opacity: 0.90;
}
a.tt:hover span.overlay{ /* different middle bg for stretch */
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
        z-index:27;
    padding: 0 8px; 
    background: #E4EBF0;
    width: 250px;
}
```